# Refresh takes the webpage to homepage instead of showing present search result again

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web

I am making a webpage which fetches query results from database.
The problem is whenever I reload page in **Chorme**, it redirects the page back to the home page instead of loading the same page again albeit it is redirecting correctly in FireFox and Safari.

For Example:
If the search URl is : **http://bug.xyz.com/#/?bug_package=Demo&ndays=0**
When I reload/refresh the page in chrome it takes me back to **http://bug.xyz.com/** but I want it to reload the present URL only.

Language used: JavaScript

P.S. The link is for example purpose only and it will not work as the website is on intranet only.

Answer (score 0):

My only thought is, what is the `/#/` bit for. It may be what's causing your problem.

Otherwise you'll need to post some code.

Comment: Thanks for replying :). But I think it's not the problem because while building this website I have taken help in code from another company's website it also has this /#/ bit but it is able to refresh the page with current search. I'm not sure I can post code because I have no idea which part is causing this.